# How do you load a partial view within an accordian div in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, accordion

so currently, I have the page loading this:

```
    <div class="accordion">
        <h2><a href="#">Pending Flyers</a></h2>
        <div id="flyers-0" class="accordion-item"><% Html.RenderPartial("ManageFlyers", new { flyers = pendingFlyersWithCategory }); %></div>
        <h2><a href="#">Approved Flyers</a></h2>
        <div id="flyers-1" class="accordion-item"><% Html.RenderPartial("ManageFlyers", new  { flyers = approvedFlyersWithCategory }); %></div>
        <h2><a href="#">Denied Flyers</a></h2>
        <div id="flyers-2" class="accordion-item"><% Html.RenderPartial("ManageFlyers", new  { flyers = deniedFlyersWithCategory }); %></div>
        <h2><a href="#">Published Flyers</a></h2>
        <div id="flyers-3" class="accordion-item"><% Html.RenderPartial("ManageFlyers", new  { flyers = publishedFlyersWithCategory }); %></div>
        <h2><a href="#">Expired Flyers</a></h2>
        <div id="flyers-4" class="accordion-item"><% Html.RenderPartial("ManageFlyers", new  { flyers = expiredFlyersWithCategory }); %></div>
    </div>
```

with this java script to do the accordion stuff:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if ($('.accordion').length > 0) {
        $('.accordion-item').hide();
        $('.accordion-selected').show();

        $('.accordion h2').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.accordion-item').slideToggle('slow');
        });

        $('.accordion h2 a').click(function () {
            var element = $(this).parent().next('.accordion-item');
            element.slideToggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
    }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         // Accordian state restore
         var accord = '<%= Session["accordianIndex"] %>';
         var currentindex = 0;

         if (accord != "") {
             currentindex = accord;
         }

         $("#flyers-" + currentindex).slideToggle("slow");
         // end Accordian state restore
     });

     $("div.description").expander({
         slicePoint: 200
     });
</script>
```

I want to set it up to use AJAX to load the partial views and insert them when that part of the accordion is expanded in order to speed up the initial loading of the page.

I have tried both the `<%= Ajax.ActionLink ... %>` and javascript to load it, but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you target the right technology in the tags, which in this case is `ASP.NET MVC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it doesn't exactly do it when the data is requested, but I changed some stuff around and was able to get the desired functionality by doing the following:

within `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` I used

```
$('#flyers-0').load('<%= Url.Action("ManageFlyers", new { stuff }) %>');
```

for each of the accordion tabs. so now the page initially loads much quicker and then it fills in the divs when the data is loaded. If the div isn't opened until the data is loaded, they won't know it did any background stuff, otherwise it just says "Loading..." and be filled in soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup Controller Actions (PartialViewResult) for these partials you could load them with the jQuery $.ajax call. You would write something like

```
$.ajax({ url: /controller/Action, data: {stuff} });
```

This approach would let you offset your load times like you describe in a click method or some other event when you toggle the accordion.

**UPDATE**:

If you already have the data local to this page, I would suggest doing something like a [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template and just $("div").append() the data to the page you are on where div is the selector you want to contain the data in.

Comment: I looked into that, although I couldn't find a way to put the data into it without doing a number of database queries that have already been done to get to this point.

Comment: Ahh -- I guess I didn't realize that the data was already available to the view.